# $x_0 \geq 2$ and $x_n = 2 + \sqrt{x_{n−1} − 2}$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Monotone Convergence THM to prover $x_n \to 2$ or $x_n \to 3$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am looking for feedback and help on my proof. Please let me know what you think, as well as help me spot potential holes/errors/leaps in logic.

> Suppose that $x_0 \geq 2$ and $x_n = 2 + \sqrt{x_{n−1} − 2}$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to prove that either $x_n \to 2$ or $x_n \to 3$  as $n\to\infty$.

My attempt:

suppose $x_0 \ge 2$ and $x_{n}=2 + \sqrt{x_{n-1}-2}$

if $(x_n)$ is not decreasing, then there exists some first $x_{n+1}$ such that $x_{n+1}>x_n$. so, $2 + \sqrt{x_{n}-2}>x_n \implies$
$\sqrt{x_{n}-2}>x_n-2 \implies$
$x_{n}-2>(x_n-2)^2 \implies x_n-2<1$, and so $x_n<3$.
therefore $0\le \sqrt{x_n-2}<1$, and so $x_{n+1}<3$, so $(x_n)$ is bounded above by $3$. if there exists a first $k>n+1$ such that $x_k<x_{k-1}$, then $x_{k-1}>2+\sqrt{x_{k-1}-2}$ and so
$(x_{k-1}-2)^2>x_{k-1}-2 \implies x_{k-1}-2 >1 \implies x_{k-1}>3$, which contradicts the previous bound. therefore, the sequence is monotone  and bounded for all $k \ge  n$.

suppose $(x_n)$ is decreasing.
then $(x_n)$ is bounded below by $2$.

Therefore, in either case the sequence is both monotone and bounded.

therefore it converges by monotone convergence theorem.
suppose it converges to $L$. then, $\lim x_n=\lim (2 + \sqrt{x_{n-1}-2})$ and so
$\lim x_n -2= \lim \sqrt{x_{n-1}-2}$
so
$(L-2)^2=L-2$ and so $L^2-4L+4=L-2$
$L^2-5L+6=0$
$(L-2)(L-3)=0$, so $L=2$ or $L=3$

Comment: The point of my answer was to alter the strategy of assuming that the sequence was decreasing, or was increasing.  Instead, assume (in effect) that $x_0 < 3$ or $x_0 > 3$, and see where each Case leads.  This makes the analysis easier for you, and also makes the posting easier for others to read.  Ask yourself, which posting will a reviewer find easier to digest, yours or mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all correct. I might say that, where you address the case $(x_n)$ not decreasing, it might be more 'complete' (depending on who's marking your work!) to add that $x_n-2>0$ which justifies some of your inequalities. I would also say that you should mention you've shown: $$x_{n+1}>x_n\implies x_{n+1}<3$$And you need one more (simple, and again the need for this nitpicking depends on who's marking your work) logical step to show that this means $x_n<3$ for *all* $n$.

We know $2+\sqrt{x-2}>x$ if $x\in(2,3)$, so the iteration accordingly tends to $3$ for all choices of $x_0\neq2$. That is, $2$ is not a *stable* fixed point. As user2661923 points out, $3$ *is* a stable fixed point. Fix $1/2<c<1$. I would explain the attraction to $3$ by noting the derivative of the iterating map is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}$ is contained in $[0,c]$ for all $x\ge2+1/4c^2$, and the image of $[2+1/4c^2,\infty)$ under this map is contained again in $[2+1/4c^2,\infty)$, so by the contraction mapping principle the iterations will necessarily converge to a unique stable fixed point in $[2+1/4c^2,\infty)$, namely $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat *off-topic*:

For what it's worth, I would have approached the problem in a totally different manner.

Without Loss of Generality $x_0 \neq 2$ and $x_0 \neq 3$, else the sequence would be equivalent to either $2,2,2,\cdots,$ or $3,3,3,\cdots.$

So, I would attack the two cases of $2 < x_0 < 3$ and $3 < x_0$ separately.

So, the problem has the following aspects:

- $\displaystyle x_{n+1} = 2 + \sqrt{x_n - 2}.$
- $\displaystyle x_{n+1} - x_n = 2 + 
  \sqrt{x_n - 2} - x_n $ 
  $= ~\displaystyle \sqrt{x_n - 2} \times 
  \left[1 - \sqrt{x_n - 2}\right].$
- **If** the limit, $(L)$ exists, it must satisfy 
  $\displaystyle L = 2 + \sqrt{L-2} \implies L - 2 = \sqrt{L-2} \implies \sqrt{L - 2} \in \{0,1\}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1} ~: 2 < x_0 < 3}$

$x_n < 3 \implies x_{n+1} < 3.$ 
Therefore, the sequence is bounded above by $(3)$.

Further, immediate that if $2 < x_n < 3$, that **both** of the factors of $x_{n+1} - x_n$ are positive.

Therefore, $2 < x_n < 3 \implies x_n < x_{n+1} < 3$.

So, the sequence is bounded above and increasing.

Therefore, the sequence must be convergent, and so must converge to $3$, rather than $2$.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2} ~: 3 < x_0}$

$x_n > 3 \implies x_{n+1} > 3.$ 
Therefore, the sequence is bounded below by $(3)$.

Further, immediate that if $3 < x_n$, that **one** of the factors of $x_{n+1} - x_n$ is positive, and the **other** factor is negative.

Therefore, $3 < x_n \implies 3 < x_{n+1} < x_n$.

So, the sequence is bounded below and decreasing.

Therefore, the sequence must be convergent, and so must converge to $3$, rather than $2$.

Answer (score 0):

**An interesting observation:**

Let $x_n= x_{n-1}=t$ for very large $n$, then
$x_n=2+\sqrt{x_{n-1}-2} \implies t=2+\sqrt{t-2} \implies t^2-5x+6=0 \implies t=2,3$. We can see  that $x_0=2,\implies x_1=2,.....,x_{\infty}=2$. so 2 and 3 are fixed point point  of the map.

Interestingly, whether  $x_0$ is real ($\ne 2,3$) or non-real: Numerically,
the sequence tends to 3 namely, $x_{\infty}\to 3$. Notice the 3 is higher of two numbers $2,3$. I have tried $x_0=0, \pm 1,\pm i,1\pm i, 1.9,2.1,2.9,3.1...$